# Audio not playing on mobile browser. How can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, audio

I am creating a language-learning app currently. The situation is the following:

It's a chat app, every time I send a message to the server, the server sends a response back. I then use the google text-to-speech API and want it to be read out loud. This works fine on desktop browser, but the mobile browser isn't letting me do this.

I read that this is on purpose that they don't let you autoplay this, but is there any way around this? Because it's a pretty vital part of my application.

At the moment I use the react-h5-audio-player package. Every time the audioUrl changes (when I get a new message from the server) it should start playing

```
  <AudioPlayer
       autoPlay
       src={audioUrl}
       onPlay={(e) => console.log("onPlay")}
  />
```

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you're facing an issue with auto-playing audio on mobile browsers, which is a common restriction due to user experience and data consumption concerns.

One way to work around this limitation is to allow the user to initiate the audio playback themselves. You can provide a play button or some user-triggered event (like a click) that starts the audio playback.

Try this solution:

```html
   
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import AudioPlayer from 'react-h5-audio-player';

function MyComponent() {
  const [audioUrl, setAudioUrl] = useState(null);

  // Function to handle when a new message is received
  const handleNewMessage = (newAudioUrl) => {
    setAudioUrl(newAudioUrl);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => {audioUrl && document.getElementById('audio').play()}}>Play Audio</button>
      <AudioPlayer
        id="audio"
        src={audioUrl}
        onPlay={(e) => console.log("onPlay")}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: But I would like a solution without the user having to click a button. From the moment I receive a response form the server i want it to be read out loud without any action of the user.